# Questions without answers, questions with no accepted answer

Tags: discussion

Currently, we have [**254 questions with no answer at all**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/unanswered), and scrolling through a few pages of questions, there is a good deal of questions with no accepted-mark.

Can I suggest we all skim through the unanswered questions and make an effort to answer them? Or, if they are unsalvageable, maybe get rid of them?

How can we encourage (particularly new) users to tick the accepted box? It is good for everyone that questions have accepted answers.

I do not mean that we should have accepted-ticks on every single questions, some will, by the nature of the Q, not have a single, perfect answer. I am merely suggesting that we should encourage people (and teach them) how this works.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

SE no longer addresses questions without an excepted answer per my understanding and it would be up to the OP to accept one but I recall discussing this topic with John last year.

That said we have in the past tried to address and see if we could get some of them answered by editing a majority of them and cleaning their tags.

I think a few members have tried scoping outside of SE to forum sites for inkscape and gimp but I can understand why they would think we were spamming.

I would suggest maybe sharing them socially and I do know we could always place bounties on the questions to possibly gain answers to the unanswered questions.

All the efforts we originally placed were in fact when we were in beta but coming through the questions to throw them in the Q may be in order again.  If you feel you can give a valued answer to one you come across by all means answer it.

I do know when we can find time I do beleive some can be modified or marked as duplicate but it is still a timely process..  hope this answers your question.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by _"SE no longer addresses questions without an excepted answer per my understanding and it would be up to the OP to accept one but I recall discussing this topic with John last year."_? SE no longer addresses? What does that mean? What came out of your discussion with JohnB? Of course it is up to the OP to accept, but there are instances were we could remind/teach people to do it. I am merely suggesting we could skim through the unanswered list, and finding questions of value unanswered, try to do so. Or, if they are impossible, mark as duplicate or delete.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's part of a wider issue. We have no automatic induction here, so new users understandably overlook the hard-to-find instructions for using the site.

I personally feel we need some special attention applied upstairs to help us better convert the huge amount of search engine traffic we receive.

Just the option to display a welcoming induction message to any new users could go a long way to improving our conversion rates.

This is all my opinion, which can often be wrong. :)

Comment: Check out the site in an incognito window to see what we show to random Google passersby - I think it's different now than when you signed up.